# Term in English for short physical exercise in the middle of a lesson - Физкульминутка

Tags: terminology

In Russian, there is a popular concept "Физкульминутка" (Physical culture minute) - this is a very short break in the middle of a lesson for physical exercise to rest.
Is there a term in English for this?
What do you call these breaks - exercises like "clap your hands, stamp your feet, ..."?

Comment: In elementary school, the much longer and classic favorite academic subject of all school children is 'recess', a much longer break.

Answer (score 2):

I’m not aware of any established term, but “(short) exercise break” is a clear term that needs no definition. Here are some examples in use:

- > [Classroom Exercise Breaks for Elementary Students](https://kidshealth.org/en/parents/elementary-exercises.html)
- > One to two exercise breaks, held daily in school, will contribute significantly to the goal of a total of 30 minutes of activity each day for every child. — [Active Breaks](https://www.dchs.nhs.uk/our-services/find_services_by_topic/cyph/download?nid=823&did=23253) (download)
- > [Short exercise breaks during class improve concentration](https://theconversation.com/amp/short-exercise-breaks-during-class-improve-concentration-for-senior-students-140545)

Alternatively, I have also seen the following used, less commonly:

- [Movement break](https://buildingmomentuminschools.blog/2018/09/14/movement-breaks-in-the-classroom/amp/)
- [Fitness break](http://www.amchp.org/AboutTitleV/Resources/Documents/Tips%20-%20Fitness%20Breaks.pdf) (seems to indicate a bit more rigor)
- [Physical activity break](https://www.actionforhealthykids.org/activity/classroom-physical-activity-breaks/) (a bit wordy and slightly formal)

The term “[brain break](https://www.weareteachers.com/brain-breaks-for-kids/)” is close but the activities it covers don’t all involve exercise (such as  mindfulness).

Comment: Thanks. But if I understand correctly, "exercise" can mean not only physical activity, but also mental one: tasks in textbooks can also be called exercises.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be looking for the term "***brain break***":

> A brain break is a break from whatever kids
> are focusing on. Short brain breaks during work time have been shown
> to have real benefits. They reduce stress and frustration and increase
> attention and productivity. (1)
>
> In the classroom, brain breaks are quick, structured breaks using physical movement, mindfulness exercises, or sensory activities. Brain breaks can be done individually (like deep breathing) or as a whole class (like a round of Simon Says). (2)
>
> understood.org [(1)](https://www.understood.org/en/school-learning/learning-at-home/homework-study-skills/brain-breaks-what-you-need-to-know#:%7E:text=What%20Is%20a%20Brain%20Break,and%20increase%20attention%20and%20productivity.) & [(2)](https://www.understood.org/en/school-learning/for-educators/teaching-strategies/evidence-based-behavior-strategy-brain-breaks)

---

> A brain break is a short mental break that is taken during regular
> intervals during classroom instruction. Brain breaks are usually
> limited to five minutes and work best when they incorporate physical
> activities.
>
> [thoughtco.com](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-a-brain-break-2081615)

Answer (score 0):

Exercise break. Or minute if you will.

English is relatively resistant to merging words ad hoc.

Comment: Laurel has already covered 'exercise break'. '[Short] exercise break' covers both terms.